# How can we define a single reusable error handler activity web activity to send out the email in case of failure anywhere in the ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can we define a single web activity to send out the email in case of failure anywhere in the ADF pipeline in any activity  -

I don't want to copy this activity to the "Failed" arrows for each activity  - specially when I also have "If" and "For Each" sort of nested activities in my pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very sorry, Azure data factory does not currently support centralized error capture. We can vote for these feature requests in UserVoice:

- [try catch functionality in Azure Data Factory](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40779019-try-catch-functionality-in-azure-data-factory)
- [Throw Error Activity](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34301983-throw-error-activity?page=1&per_page=20)

The only way to solve this is by linking every activity to his own "Send email on failure" activity. We can copy and paste the "Send email on failure" activity by right-clicking the activity. Like the below example.

[image]